# customize swagger import to postman

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, postman

I would like to import into postman with this setup

Request names as the relative url:

[image]

{{url}} variable in URL:

[image]

body filled with sample post data:

[image]

And custom headers:
[image]

Is this possible? I was able to achieve this in web api with 0 documentation by using a simple script and help page sample generator.

Comment: Ya, that would be cool. I won't answer unless someone has a way to do it, but as of .net core 2.0 only modifications using method comments was the only way to adjust the output and even that seemed limited. Something like a yaml converter to import specification into Postman.

Comment: meh, worst case i can build the controller myself, I can get all the details from injecting IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider, I just don't feel like coding the sample generated body